# Linking CXX executable ERROR [Netbeans C++]

Tags: c++, netbeans, makefile, cmake

I'm trying to create a C++ project with an existing CMakeLists.txt file, but I have an error "Running make failed" in Netbeans C++ IDE. Here is the Build Output :

> cd '/home/hamani/NetBeansProjects/BNproject'
>
> /usr/bin/make -f Makefile
>
> Scanning dependencies of target bnproject
>
> [ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/bnproject.dir/main.cpp.o
>
> [ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/bnproject.dir/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp.o
>
> [100%] Linking CXX executable bnproject
>
> CMakeFiles/bnproject.dir/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp.o: dans la fonction « main »:
>
> /home/hamani/NetBeansProjects/BNproject/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp:514:
>   définitions multiples de « main »
>
> CMakeFiles/bnproject.dir/main.cpp.o:/home/hamani/NetBeansProjects/BNproject/main.cpp:4: défini pour la première fois ici
>
> CMakeFiles/bnproject.dir/main.cpp.o: dans la fonction « gum::HashTable, std::allocator >, int, std::allocator, std::allocator >, int> > > ::HashTable(unsigned long, bool, bool) »: /home/hamani/usr/include/agrum/core/hashTable.tcc:1573: référence indéfinie vers « gum::**debug**::__inc_creation(char const*, char const*, long, char const*, void const*, int) »
>
> CMakeFiles/bnproject.dir/main.cpp.o: dans la fonction « gum::HashTable, std::allocator >, int, std::allocator, std::allocator >, int> > >::~HashTable() »:
>
> /home/hamani/usr/include/agrum/core/hashTable.tcc:1675: référence indéfinie vers « gum::**debug**::__inc_deletion(char const*, char const*, long, char const*, void const*)
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> CMakeFiles/bnproject.dir/build.make:120 : la recette pour la cible « bnproject » a échouée
>
> make[2]: *** [bnproject] Erreur 1
>
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67 : la recette pour la cible « CMakeFiles/bnproject.dir/all » a échouée
>
> make[1]: ***[CMakeFiles/bnproject.dir/all] Erreur 2
>
> Makefile:83 : la recette pour la cible « all » a échouée
>
> make: *** [all] Erreur 2
>
> BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 8s)

I'm using a library called **aGrUM** (https://forge.lip6.fr/projects/aGrUM/wiki) on Ubuntu 16.04, I installed it under the path

> ~/usr

I installed aGrUM in RELEASE mode, not in DEBUG mode

> python act install release -d ~/usr

In **Pre-Build Action**, Netbeans suggests me these **arguments** :

> -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${IDE_CC} -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${IDE_CXX} -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG="-g3 -gdwarf-2" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG="-g3 -gdwarf-2" -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON

so I think I have to change the value of -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to "RELEASE", to be compatible with my CMakeLists.txt.

Here is my **CMakeLists.txt** :

```
project(BNPROJECT)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++11")

# do not forget to change this line if needed ("act install -d...")
#set(AGRUM_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY "installation_path")
set(AGRUM_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY "~/usr")
set(aGrUM_DIR "${AGRUM_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY}/lib/cmake/aGrUM/")

find_package(aGrUM)

if (aGrUM_FOUND)
  include_directories(${AGRUM_INCLUDE_DIR})
  link_directories(${AGRUM_LIB_DIR})
else (aGrUM_FOUND)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Please install aGrUM")
endif (aGrUM_FOUND)

# cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG
# or
# cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE
#     RELEASE is the default option (thanks to the next 3 lines)
if( NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE )
  set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif()

file(GLOB_RECURSE BNPROJECT_SOURCE ${BNPROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE BNPROJECT_INCLUDE ${BNPROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h)

add_executable (bnproject ${BNPROJECT_SOURCE})

if ($CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE  STREQUAL "RELEASE") # release : act install release
  target_link_libraries(bnproject agrum)
else() # debug : act install debug
  #target_link_libraries(bnproject agrum-dbg)
  target_link_libraries(bnproject agrum)
endif()
```

and here is my **main.cpp** (example here : http://www-desir.lip6.fr/~phw/aGrUM/officiel/doxygen/db/db6/using_agrum.html) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <agrum/core/hashTable.h>

int main(void) {
  gum::HashTable<std::string,int> h;

  h.insert("Hello",1);
  h.insert("World",2);

  std::cout<<h<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to [Netbeans] and [makefile]. Looks like a bug inside aGrUm, but the example contains still a lot of code. Can you reduce the problem further?

Comment: I don't think so. It's just related to Netbeans project configuration, because it works very well without IDE (by compiling and running the program in a terminal with the command "cmake" and "make"). The problem arises only when I want to create a new project in Netbeans with the same CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmake finds more than one main function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22176957/cmake-finds-more-than-one-main-function)